# Where is the Aref pin for Attitny88

Tags: voltage-level, attiny

I would like to use the external analog refence voltage in an Attiny88 project I am working on that will be powered with batteries.

However, the datasheet for this processor does not show an Aref pin like other versions of the attiny, like attiny85 and attiny84, where it is usually the pin PA0 or PB0. Does anyone know where is the pin for the external voltage reference in attiny88 (e.i. Aref pin)? Does this chip has the functionality for an external analog reference voltage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in the detailed information for the ADMUX register in the ADC section of the datasheet, the ATtiny88 has no external voltage reference. Consider using a ATmega8 or ATmega88PB instead.